# Rails, collection select style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to style a collection select without any luck... Currently, I am picking a meal_size like this:

```
= f.input :meal_size_id, collection: @meal.meal_sizes
```

Which generates

```
<div class="form-group select optional order_meal_size_id">
<select class="select optional form-control" placeholder="Meal size" name="order[meal_size_id]" id="order_meal_size_id">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="10">Small</option>
   <option value="11">Medium</option>
   <option value="12">Large</option>
</select>
</div>
```

However, what I want is to have a whole div inside the option tag, and not just some plain text. Also, I would like the options to be listed, rather than shown in a dropdown. Any ideas on how to accomplish that :? Thank you!

Edit:
Previously, my meal_sizes were picked using jquery. The divs were generated like this:

```
= div_for(meal_size, class: "col-xs-4")
  .bold
    = meal_size.name
  .prices
    = meal_size.price
  .short_description
    = meal_size.description
```

And I had this code to put the selected ones in a hidden field

```
  $('.meal_size').click ->
    html_id = $(this).attr('id')
    meal_size_id = html_id.split('_')[2]
    $("#order_meal_size_id").val(meal_size_id);
    return
```

I would like to have the same as an option so that when picking them I am not using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...what I want is to have a whole div inside the option tag

As far as I know, it is invalid to have any other html tags inside of an option tag.

> Also, I would like the options to be listed, rather than shown in a
>   dropdown. Any ideas on how to accomplish that

Select tag in html has a size attribute, eg  which shows the first n options in the select tag. You could write some code in rails to make the size attribute equal to the count of the collection you are displaying in the drop down list.

For example, you could add `{ size: @meal.meal_sizes.count }` to the html options hash of the select tag.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:meal_size_id, @meal.meal_sizes, :id, :name, {:prompt => false}, { class: "form-control", size: @meal.meal_sizes.count }) %>
```

Comment: Firstly, I made my options as divs and put the selected ones in a hidden field using jquery. Everything was fine. Later, I was told that using jquery for that is lame and that I should use collection for the input. If a div inse option tag is invalid I will just return to the previus method...

Comment: Looking at the [html5 spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-option-element.html#the-option-element) on this site, its lists that the content model is only 'Text'. That means only text is permitted inside of an option tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :meal_sizes, class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= collection_select(:meal_sizes, @meal.meal_sizes, :id, :name, {:prompt => false}, class: "form-control") %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still shows the inputs as a dropdown :/

Comment: Can you please the also mention your expected html...It will make picture a bit more clear

Comment: I updated my question with the div I expect inside the option :)

Answer (score 1):

You should Use This:-
Make your method(meal_sizes) as return like and pass it in the collection

```
arr = ["<div>Small</div>","<div>Medium</div>","<div>Large</div>"]

f.input :meal_size_id, collection: arr
```